# Is there a way to alert on disk usage (or disk space left) prominently in iOS?

Tags: ios, disk-space

Is there a way to show disk usage (and disk space left) prominently in iOS by issuing alerts when threshold is met?

I wish I could see my disk usage (and remaining disk space) like "10GB/256GB remaining" prominently every time I use my iPhone (iPhone 13, iOS 15) much like I can see the date/time and battery % every time.

Ideally I can set a threshold, below which the OS will alert me rather than depend on the OS to decide that.

Is there a way I can do this on iOS 15?

Comment: We strongly prefer one question per question. I’ll edit this so it’s for one os. Feel free to ask a second question for the second OS if needed. I see 4 questions. 1 how to alert and 2 how to see times two different OS in the first version of this. Great detail, let’s be sure we get the iOS experts on the iOS question.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the status bar where date, time, battery status etc. are displayed, but you can find apps that can show disk usage in the Notification Center. [Here's one](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/sys-info-widget/id974744046) example. No alerts, but you can get the info with one swipe.